# Public Key Authentication not work on Windows 10 Professional

Tags: windows, ssh, public-key

I have been trying to configure OpenSSH for my Windows 10 Professional Edition media server.  I can get normal password login working without issue but I am trying to set up public key authentication.

I have edited my `sshd_config` file to allow for public key authentication.  The client and the server are running `ssh-agent`.  I've copied and pasted my SSH public key from the client computer into the file `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` since the account is an administrator account.
Permissions on the above file are set the same as the other key files in the directory of being just SYSTEM and Administrators both with full control and no one else is listed.

I added debug logging and when I try to connect using the public key, I get this:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user uther service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: user uther matched group list administrators at line 84
debug1: userauth-request for user uther service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg ssh-rsa pkblob RSA SHA256:jcQNaVuxvH90SIh4zu8xduBqJaav1WFQJIov3hiFSFM [preauth]
debug1: trying public key file C:\\ProgramData\\ssh\\administrators_authorized_keys
Failed publickey for uther from 10.0.0.24 port 60432 ssh2: RSA SHA256:jcQNaVuxvH90SIh4zu8xduBqJaav1WFQJIov3hiFSFM
debug1: userauth-request for user uther service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
```

I'm at a loss of how to resolve this.  I literally cut and paste the text from id_rsa.pub on the client to the server in the administrators authorized keys file using Remote Desktop.  There doesn't seem to be a permissions error, I can't figure out why it won't authenticate.

I would appreciate any help anyone could offer in getting this working.  It isn't critical, SSH isn't exposed to the Internet, but some of the scripts I use would do much better with public key authentication.

I should also note when I set up the server I used my Microsoft account, I have been wondering if that has anything to do with it, so I may try to set up a straight local account and see if that fixes it.

EDIT:  I attempted to create a local user account, but I cannot.  Even when I try to use `control userpasswords2` the box comes up but all the options to create an account are disabled.  I'm thinking this must be because I have Windows 10 Professional and not some higher and most expensive edition.

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: I did, it only said that the authentication failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by commenting out the lines:

```
Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Then I placed the authorized keys into the normal file `~\.ssh\authorized_keys` like any other time I've used ssh.  I saw this didn't work for a lot of people when I did my initial research and had discounted it.

Comment: ...this and I also had to declare `AllowUsers edoardo@192.168.1.1` in config

Answer (score 5):

Use this sequence of commands in PowerShell to correct permission of `administrators_authorized_keys`

```
$acl = Get-Acl C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)
$administratorsRule = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("Administrators","FullControl","Allow")
$systemRule = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("SYSTEM","FullControl","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($administratorsRule)
$acl.SetAccessRule($systemRule)
$acl | Set-Acl
```

Comment: YESSSS
You made my day
i was wondering how to do this on windows as its mostly permissions issues with ssh connections.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [answer by Sergio Cabral](https://serverfault.com/a/1042829/191799), the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#authorizedkeysfile) provides another option to apply the appropriate permissions:

```
icacls.exe "C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /inheritance:r /grant "Administrators:F" /grant "SYSTEM:F"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sergio Cabral's answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```
$systemRule = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("SYSTEM","FullControl","Allow")
$administratorsRule = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("Administrators","FullControl","Allow")
$acl = Get-Acl C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys
$acl.SetAccessRule($systemRule)
$acl.SetAccessRule($administratorsRule)
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)
$acl | Set-Acl
```

Answer (score -1):

$systemRule = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("SYSTEM","FullControl","Allow")
$administratorsRule = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("Administrators","FullControl","Allow")
$acl = Get-Acl C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys
$acl.SetAccessRule($systemRule)
$acl.SetAccessRule($administratorsRule)
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)
$acl | Set-Ac[l](https://essentialshoodie.co/t-shirts/)